# Parsing XML data of testng-results.xml

Tags: xml

I am new to XML and as part of test I wanted to parse the TESTNG testng-results.xml to get the following data for each tests in the Suite:

TestName:
Result:
Test Execution Time Stamp:

Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: Please improve your question. we don't know anything about the `testng-results.xml` you mentioned so there is no way to answer.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for it. I was able to solve it using the Sax parser